# Why is this question regarding the use of different kinds of HTML tags considered primarily opinion based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold, opinion-based

I asked [a question about HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53527058/5616681) the other day, mainly out of curiosity and also because I felt like it was sort of "missing" from SO and anywhere else I looked. Seems like that feeling is not shared by many since now it got downvoted and put on hold.

[image: Screenshot of question about "downsides to using HTML5 semantic tags"]

I am confused. After rereading my question I am not sure how it can be misunderstood? Essentially it is "*What can happen when you throw new standards on outdated software?*" It seems to me like something that is very measurable and objective. Is there some hidden policy here?

Comment: If it's not POB, then it's classically "too broad", since your last (of four) question is "...(*anything*)?"

Comment: Now in the end I finally did find [the question I was after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967286/degradation-issues-for-html5-semantic-tags-article-footer-header). A nice example that wording makes all the difference.

Comment: Or, a nice example of how the standards for questions have changed in 8+ years...

Comment: @Heretic Monkey: I'm not seeing how that question would be treated any differently today than it was 8+ years ago. It's the same as this question, just asked in an era where HTML5 was still very new and compatibility was still a major concern for most developers.

Comment: ... the last sentence of that other question is problematic but could probably be edited out.

Answer (score 9):

"It depends."

That would be a satisfactory answer to your question, given that the answer is and will be constantly evolving with improvements to browser technology.

If you're lucky, it will work with some quirks.  Some browsers *may* decay to using the older `div` style.  If you're unfortunate, your entire site will be broken.  It depends on what other variables are out there, such as which browser(s) you're talking about, what operating system and even what rendering engine, which can't be encapsulated simply in a single answer.

Comment: Isn't this all a case for "too broad" and not "primarily opinion-based"?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Your question isn't primarily opinion-based. All of your specific examples:

> - Will the rendering break (more) on that office machine which rolls prehistoric versions of IE?
> - backwards compatibility of css selectors like `article`?
> - strange side effects to the DOM?

... are objective hypotheses for which you're seeking verification, they're not opinions. Your question is asking for factual answers. The only issue I can see is, as Makoto points out, that there are *possibly* too many variables at play.

(In practice, there actually aren't; as the answer you have already received states, older versions of IE simply don't recognize the elements outright, which results in your first two items being true, and in the case of semantic elements that don't provide any additional functionality compared to `div`... that's pretty much it. But this is *in practice*. In my experience, questions that are only demonstrably not broad, but still may be *in theory*, are still grounds for being closed as too broad.)

Two users picked the correct choice of "too broad", but three others picked "primarily opinion-based", which makes this seem like yet another case of users getting the two close reasons mixed up. That's a trend I've noticed for many years now.

Comment: The question asks, "are there any downsites to [...]?"  That's asking for *opinions*.  Whether a given behavior of something is "a good thing" or "a downside" is an opinion, not an objective fact.